# trying to fetch the data in a nested arrays from mongodb in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

trying to fetch the data in a nested arrays from mongodb in node js

```html
exports.cities = async (req, res, next) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    let dbo = db.db(DATABASE);
    const { country_code, state_code } = req.body;
    dbo.collection("countries").find({iso2:country_code}).toArray(function (err, result) {
      //res.json(result);
      for(let i=0; i<result.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<result[i].states.state_code.length; j++){
              if(result[i].states[j].state_code == result[AP]){
                res.json(result[i].states[j])
              }
        }
        //res.json(result[i]);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6inpJ.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately our mind-readers are currently on break, so please include in detail where exactly you are stuck/what problem you are facing so other users might help you more easily. Also please be sure to include such information as text, and NOT as an image, as images are not searchable and might become unavailable (e.g. when the image host stops hosting the image).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't connect to mongo in HTTP request callbacks, connect to it once and re-use that connection.

```js
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

mongoClient.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Available via req.app.locals.db.
  app.locals.db = mongoClient.db('your-database');

  app.listen(3000); 
});
```

Instead of looping over the cursor you can just call `toArray`, I recommend you don't format your data to a string on the server, instead pass the array back as JSON to the client and let the client render it out however it wants:

```js
app.route('/results').get(async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = req.app.locals;
  const results = await db.collection('results').toArray();
  res.status(200).json(results);
});
```

Comment: the thing is when i get a country_code(iso2:"India") and state_code("AP") i need to send particular cities which are present in that state(AP) i need to do that in my api when i tried in ptython i get it but node its different can u help?
{ country_code = "IN",
state_code="AP"} this is how I am gonna give in postman